# php how to save all the values inside an array when applying a foreach function?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How can I save an array, for example,

```
['name' => 'Some_name_1', 'Quantity' => 176],
['name' => 'some_name_2', 'Quantity' => 1096],
['name' => 'some_name_3', 'Quantity' => 1598],
```

from a foreach loop?

For example, I get those values from another array by applying the `array_count_values()` function in this form:

```
Array
(
    [Some_name_1] => 176
    [Some_name_2] => 1096
    [Some_name_3] => 1598
)
```

And when I apply the `foreach()` like this

```
foreach($values as $index => $value){
        $stats=['name'=>$index,'Quantity'=>$value];
    }
```

I only get one value stored in the new array and not the three ones.

```
Array
(
    [name] => Some_name_3
    [Quantity] => 1598
)
```

(Some_name_1, and Some_name_2 weren't stored in the array)

How can I save all of them inside the array? What am I missing?

Comment: `$stats=['name'=>$index,'Quantity'=>$value];` to `$stats[]=['name'=>$index,'Quantity'=>$value];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

push to the array, your syntax is incorrect.

```
foreach(values as $index=>$value)
{
    array_push($stats, array('name'=>$index, 'quantity'=>$value));
}
```

or as Matt says above, alternate syntax:

```
foreach(values as $index=>$value)
{
    $stats[] = array('name'=>$index, 'quantity'=>$value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your foreach loop you're not appending to an array - rather overwriting each time you iterate over the values array.

Append to an array rather than overwriting using the example below.

New function:

```
foreach($values as $index => $value){
        $stats[]=['name'=>$index,'Quantity'=>$value];
    }
```